# jquery ui icon not centered on span

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a span that holds a jquery-ui icon, and an outer span that gets the error state.

However the icon is shifted up, so that part of the icon is not contained in the outer span. I can tell because with the ui-state-error, the outer span has a red background, and the icon is partially above this red area.

Any ideas why?

```
<span style="width:20px;height:20px;display:none" class="userNameInvalidIcon ui-state-error">
    <span style="display:inline-block" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"/>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: Working just fine in chrome.  And, despite years as a UI guy, I'm baffled why you'd want to set it up this way.  if you just want a border around the icon, why not set it up that way via css and drop the outer div?

Comment: I don't just want a border, I want it to have ui-state-error. I think putting a static border color and background color is the wrong way to do it, rather than using the css class that Jqueryui provides, that will change if my theme colors change. The reason i need the outer span, is if I apply the ui-state-error to the inner span there is an issue with the icon it self. I think it creates an issue of what pixels of the image sheet to use for the icon.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<span style="width:20px;height:20px;display:none" class="userNameInvalidIcon ui-state-error">
    <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this(works in FF, IE and Chrome):

```
<div style="width:17px;" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-error">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close"></span>
</div>
```

HTH

Comment: I have to have the `display:inline-block`, otherwise it does not show inline with the surrounding elements, for example, another icon next to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-icon
{
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: 100% !important; 
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: You may want to explain your answer for the benefit of the OP